# In QGIS modeler I get SQL query syntax error - in Database Manager SQL window is working fine

Tags: postgresql, qgis-modeler

I have SQL query which add record to several related tables.
When I run query in Database manager, it works fine. But when I use PostgreSQL execute SQL from algorithms in Model Designer, I get error. Also algorithm SQL Query says about Syntax error.
I have tried to remove comments, I have tried to use just part of the query, nothing helped.
So are there some rules for sql queries in algorithm "PostgreSQL execute SQL"?

Here is SQL query:

```
do $$ 
declare
    x_id_reg_nnkp_uzpf  integer;
    x_pusr_uid_nnkp     integer;
    x_id_reg_po_uzpf    integer;
    x_cuz_nnkp  integer;
    x_pusr_uid_po       integer;
    x_id_geo        integer;    -- ID GEO 
    x_id_prie_id    integer;    -- ID lok
    x_type_nnkp         TEXT DEFAULT 'NNKP';
    x_type_po           TEXT DEFAULT 'PO';

begin
    x_id_reg_nnkp_uzpf  = nextval('public.hibernate_sequence');
    x_pusr_uid_nnkp     = nextval('public.pusr_uid_nnkp_sequence');
    x_cuz_nnkp      = nextval('public.cislo_uz_nnkp_sequence');
    x_id_reg_po_uzpf    = nextval('public.hibernate_sequence');
    x_pusr_uid_po       = nextval('public.pusr_uid_po_sequence');
    x_id_geo        = nextval('public.hibernate_sequence');
    x_id_prie_id    = nextval('public.hibernate_sequence');


INSERT INTO public.reg_entita_pf
                    (id, 
                     created_by, 
                     created_date, 
                     last_modified_by, 
                     last_modified_date, 
                     "version", 
                     verzia_zaznamu, 
                     zmazany_zaznam, 
                     guid, 
                     "type", 
                     pusr_uid)
                values
                    (x_id_reg_nnkp_uzpf, 
                     'migration', 
                     now(), 
                     'migration', 
                     now(), 
                     1, 
                     1, 
                     false, 
                     gen_random_uuid(), 
                     x_type_nnkp, 
                     concat(x_type_nnkp, x_pusr_uid_nnkp));
    
    INSERT INTO public.reg_nnkp_uzpf
        (id, 
         cislo_uz, 
         zauzivany_nazov
        )
    values
        (
            x_id_reg_nnkp_uzpf,                                 -- id
            x_cuz_nnkp,                                 -- cislo_uz
            'Test 1'                        -- zauzivany_nazov
        );    
    
    INSERT INTO public.lok_priestorova_identifikacia
        (   id, 
            guid, 
            created_by, 
            created_date, 
            last_modified_by, 
            last_modified_date, 
            "version", 
            verzia_zaznamu, 
            zmazany_zaznam, 
            aktualnost_vymedzenia, 
            kontrola, 
            poznamka_k_vymedzeniu, 
            rok_platnosti, 
            vymera, 
            metoda_vymedzenia_ref_key_id, 
            presnost_zamerania_ref_key_id)
    VALUES
        (   x_id_prie_id,       -- id
            gen_random_uuid(),  -- guid
            'migration',        -- created_by
            now(),              -- created_date
            'migration',        -- last_modified_by
            now(),              -- last_modified_date
            1,                  -- version 
            1,                  -- verzia_zaznamu
            false,              -- zmazany_zaznam
            now(),  
            NULL,   
            NULL,   
            NULL,               
            0,      
            NULL,      
            NULL                
    );
        
            INSERT INTO public.geo_po_uzpf_geometria_objektivizovana_multi_polygon
                (   id, 
                    guid, 
                    created_by, 
                    created_date, 
                    last_modified_by, 
                    last_modified_date, 
                    "version", 
                    geometria, 
                    autor_ref_key_id,
                    priestorova_identifikacia_id)
            VALUES
                (   x_id_geo,           -- id
                    gen_random_uuid(),  -- guid
                    'migration',        -- created_by
                    now(),              -- created_date
                    'migration',        -- last_modified_by
                    now(),              -- last_modified_date
                    1,                  -- version 
                    null,   -- geometria
                    NULL,               -- autor_ref_key_id
                    x_id_prie_id)       
            ;
            
    
    INSERT INTO public.reg_entita_pf
                    (id, 
                     created_by, 
                     created_date, 
                     last_modified_by, 
                     last_modified_date, 
                     "version", 
                     verzia_zaznamu, 
                     zmazany_zaznam, 
                     guid, 
                     "type", 
                     pusr_uid)
                values
                    (x_id_reg_po_uzpf, 
                     'migration', 
                     now(), 
                     'migration', 
                     now(), 
                     1, 
                     1, 
                     false, 
                     gen_random_uuid(), 
                     x_type_po, 
                     concat(x_type_po, x_pusr_uid_po));
    
        INSERT INTO public.reg_po_uzpf
            (id, 
             index_uz, 
             nnkp_id, 
             poradie, 
             zauzivany_nazov, 
             priestorova_identifikacia_id)
        VALUES 
            (
             x_id_reg_po_uzpf,               
             1,                             -- index_uz 
             x_id_reg_nnkp_uzpf,            -- nnkp_id 
             1,                             
             'Test 11',                     
             x_id_prie_id                       
            );  
                    
end $$;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGIS Graphical Modeler PostgreSQL Execute and Load SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428829/qgis-graphical-modeler-postgresql-execute-and-load-sql)